# Cant resolve 'sha1'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm-install

I already run "npm install" and when I hovered sha1, the code already seen it.

[image]

but I got a error like this when I'm about to build it:

[image]

Please help me for my problem :) thanks

Comment: because the error says that `its not looking into @node_modules` as per the path of error message. Check the correct import method if you adding `sha1` as npm dependency

Comment: could you tell me what to do

Comment: Can u confirm if its installed via `package.json` dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the time or place for it, but nodejs does have built-in functionality for this stuff in crypto. ie: `var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1').update('Apple').digest("hex");`

Comment: @ShashankVivek *"@types/sha1": "^1.1.1",* yes

Comment: @ippi where can I put it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have installed the typescript definitions but not the module it self. Try running `npm i --save sha1` (please note that not `@types/sha1` which is the typescript definitions)